# R replace variable name in all dimensions of multidimensional list

Tags: r, list, rename

I have a large, multidimensional list as a result of a statistic's project. The list holds different objects, holding objects by themselves. There are also plots, matrices etc. It's a heterogeneous mix of a lot of different types and different dimensionalities.

Now I have to change the name of one variable completely. Every occurence has to be overriden. Is there a way to do this?

Here is a little example. There's no use in solving this example explicitely, as my list is much larger.

```
a <- list(entry1=list("a","b","c","xx",p=c(3,4,"xx")),
          entry2=list(matrix(c(1,2,"xx",4), nrow = 2),xx=list(6,7,8,"xx")),
          xx=list(1,2,3,4,"xx"))
```

How can I change the `xx` to `yy`? Thanks in advance!

Comment: yes there is, please post a reproducible example so we can work on ways to overcome the problem.

Comment: Do you want to rename the names of list as well from "xx" to "yy" ?

Comment: Yes, this is needed, too. Thank you